# Accessing SF Explorer on secured cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I followed the steps to secure a SF cluster using a self-signed cert and an ARM template using one of the samples. It deploys fine but I am unable to access the SF Explorer due to the security cert not being trusted. If I tell Chrome to proceed anyway I get just a blank page, no SF Explorer.

How do I get the cert installed correctly locally and tell Chrome (or other browsers) to use it? I am trying to access the SF Explorer via https instead of the normal http.

Along the same lines, how will the cluster being secure change how I deploy apps from Visual Studio and powershell commands? Have I missed some pertinent document on this or is it not well covered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the cert to the CurrentUser store on your PC should be sufficient to make it accessible for authenticating to SF Explorer. Note that this won't make the warning go away, however, as that is a function of the browser not trusting the server's certificate. You can get rid of that warning by adding the cert to the trusted store on your machine.

Once the cert is installed in the CurrentUser store, the browser should pop up a dialog to ask you to choose the cert you want to use to connect to SF Explorer.

As for deploying apps, the Publish flow in VS will automatically fetch the necessary cert metadata for secure clusters and store it in your publish profile so that the cert gets picked up from the local store at connection time, as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-visualstudio-configure-secure-connections/).

Comment: Thanks Sean. My issue was that the first time I tried this I did not yet have the cert imported locally and canceled out of the cert selection dialog. Chrome is not smart enough to show it again next time. Deploying a new cluster with a new name solved it. I also had to manually edit the publish profile in VS to get it to connect.